# Event System Error with Tridion UI (Experience Manager)

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-ui, tridion-events

We are publishing extra page using event system on publishing event of pages. 
It is working well when we publish a page from the CME. When we create a page using Tridion UI, it is created and published as expected but the event system throws error when it tries to create a target type object.

```
 try
            {
                foreach (var t in e.Targets)
                {
                    var targets = new List<TargetType>();

                   some logic

                    targets.Add(new TargetType(t.Id, page.Session)); // error is in this line

                    PublishInstructionBase pib = e.PublishTransactions.First().Instruction;
                    PublishInstruction pi = new PublishInstruction(page.Session);
                    pi.StartAt = pib.StartAt;
                    pi.RollbackOnFailure = pib.RollbackOnFailure;


                    PublishEngine.Publish(
                        items,
                        pi,
                        targets,
                        PublishPriority.Low
                    );
                }

            }
```

Exception we are getting is **InvalidURIException**

Both **t and Session** are not definitely not null which we verified by writing log over there.

Please do suggest what we can to fix the issue?

We manage to fix that by little hack putting code in try catch and creating target type manually if there is exception as we do know Tridion UI publish to staging only initially.

Thanks,
Vikas Kumar

Comment: Can you please tell us the actual error? Exception type, message and stack trace would all be helpful.

Comment: also what is the value you get from t.ID?

Comment: @JohnBax  we did get valid existing tcm uri from t.ID

Comment: okay but what was the item type? the item type of a TargetType is 65538, if the ID ends in any other number, it will throw an exception

Comment: It was the valid target type ends with 65538 only. I verified the same in gui as well.

Comment: Does the user have the rights to use the TargetType you are getting the exception on? Check page.Session.User.Name and see if that user can actually open the target type URI in the UI?

Comment: It seems like you are looping the targets - can you show us a list of all the URIS in that array? Could there be some kind of null URI in the array for preview purposes?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell without exception and stack trace, but I assume you need to read `TargetType` first and not try to create it, like this:

```
(TargetType) page.Session.GetObject(t.Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the URIs you use are not from the same Publication context and are therefore invalid.